LTspice simulation of Class B amplifier
In the 1'st picture below I provided the amplifier circuit diagram.
The 2'nd picture is showing the base signal of Q5 (green colour) and Vce signal of Q5 (blue colour). It is working as it is expected.
In 3'rd picture is same as 2nd picture only the collector-emitter signal (red colour) for Q4 is added. This red colour measurement is taken between point A and B as I put labels on the circuit.
What ı have noticed is that red measurement is going between 11.367 V and 0.142 V. What I thought as a reason for that is as follows:
Why is Vce of Q4 going between 11.367 and  0.142 V ?
Additionally;
In 4'th picture, I showed the Vbe of Q4 (turquoise colour) .
In 5'th picture, I showed the Vbe of Q10 (pink colour).

Source: My own study

Source: my own study

Source: my own study

Source: My own study

Measuring between A and B gives you Vce of Q4, not Vbe. The latter will never be above about 0.7V

okay then it is Vce, why it is going betwen around 11 V and 0.2 V ?
Another thing  when Q5 is not conducting 12 volt will be on base of Q4.  ı want to see that part. Betwen whoich two point should ı touch if ı want to see the base signal of Q4 ?  @Finbarr

It would probably make more sense to display the signal between point B and ground instead of between A and B. Point A is just the positive supply. The base of Q4 is already shown as the blue trace.

Why the Vce of Q4 is going between 11 V and around 0.2 V ? do you have any idea ? @Finbarr

Consider what happens with Q4 and Q10 in the cases where Q5 is fully on and fully off.

I considered it and couldn't understand the reason that is why ı am asking here sir, do you have any suggestion ? @Finbarr

Maybe read the Wikipedia article on Class B amplifiers

The body diode of M6 is always conducting because source and drain are interchanged.

Hello sir, I noticed that my p channel connection was wrong so I fixed it. still it is going between around 11.2 V and 0.7 V. Do you have any other suggestion @Jens

Suggestion for what? The circuit appears to be working exactly as it's designed to.

To answer your question it may be helpful to know, which voltages you expect. I would not call this a class B amplifier because it is not designed as analog amplifier.
